# GitPython -- How to 'git stash' changes to a GitPython repository?

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I have a repo created via GitPython library that has some uncommitted changes. I want to stash those changes. How do I do it?

Searching for "stash" in the GitPython [docs](http://gitpython.readthedocs.org/en/stable/reference.html) returned no results.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Per the docs, ["Using git directly"](http://gitpython.readthedocs.org/en/stable/tutorial.html#using-git-directly):

> In case you are missing functionality as it has not been wrapped, you may
>     conveniently use the git command directly. It is owned by each repository
>     instance.

Thus, you could call `git stash save` with

```
repo.git.stash('save')
```

Comment: Thanks! I searched for "stash" in the docs but didn't find it, nor did I find any 'stash' function in the Repo class. And I missed this part of the documentation, hence the confusion.

Comment: Since *how you know* is often more interesting than *what you know*, I'll mention that I found this by googling "gitpython stash", finding [this bug report](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/issues/70) and then consulting [the docs](http://gitpython.readthedocs.org/en/stable/tutorial.html) to find out more about `repo.git`.

Comment: Thanks for that! I googled "how to stash gitpython repo" and similar queries, but I guess I was trying too hard to find an already existing Q/A post on some forum. Sometimes a minimalistic query like yours works better. :)